# Copy existing Realm Mobile Database to Realm Object Server

Tags: realm

Say I create an app that uses Realm Mobile Database and down the road I want to allow users to sync data between devices using the Realm Object Server, is this possible?

Or if I want to have syncing do I have to factor this in from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly no. Local Realm files and synchronized Realm files have slightly differing file formats. As such, as of writing, it's not possible to 'promote' a local Realm to a synchronized Realm after it's been created.

If you do want to start synchronizing Realm data at a later date, the easiest solution would be to run a one-off operation where the data in the local Realm is copied into the synchronized the first time it is created.

Comment: What would be the recommended way of copying the data to what could be a significantly large Realm?

Comment: How big are we talking here? There wouldn't really be any recommended ways short of simply iterating through each object and copying it to the new Realm. Realm uses KVC, so it should be pretty straightforward to make a very low level operation to do it. I'd also recommend liberally using `@autoreleasepool` around each copy transaction to make sure memory usage doesn't unnecessarily spike.

Comment: Thank you. The realm in question is 37mb, which come to think of it is probably pretty small. Will copying like this keep all the relationships?

Comment: No problems! Realm files usually keep extra space around for threaded snapshots and notification transactions, so it's possible your actual data is less than that. Hmmm, no I don't think so. You'd have to explicitly account for relations and make sure those objects are duplicated too. (Otherwise you might inadvertantly try to reference a related object from the original Realm.) Sorry!